# how to add data and the print it in sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I inserted to database as follows

```
insert  into `sample`(`id`,`month`,`revenue`) values 

(1,'Jan','1'),
(2,'Jan','1'),
(3,'Jan','1'),

(4,'FEB','1'),
(5,'feb','1'),
(6,'feb','1'),
(7,'feb','1'),
```

Am trying to pull this data from database
1: i want to add up all the values of revenue for month of Jan in sql query (eg 1+1+1) and then print the records for the month of jan

2: i want to add up all the values of revenue for the month of feb in sql query (eg 1+1+1) and then print the records for the month of feb

how can i achieve that, below is my php for retrieval

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("vero_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['month'] . "\t" . $row['revenue']. "\n";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: i would use the month number not shortened name

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to achieve what you expect:

```
Select Month, Sum(revenue) From Sample GROUP BY MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum for each month you can run the following - note that you can add a WHERE clause to filter on a per month basis.

```
SELECT month, sum(revenue) FROM sample GROUP BY month
```

To get the unique listing of months:

```
SELECT DISTINCT month from sample
```

To get exactly what you are after, combine the above two queries. You wouldn't want to do this in one query as you are grouping data - You can use the compute power of PHP to do your SUM function if you want as well, that way you are only executing one query.

Ultimately, depends on how often you will be hitting the database.

Comment: it displays the following error when i run the query                     Notice: Undefined index: revenue in C:\xampp\htdocs\values.php on line 19
feb//
Notice: Undefined index: revenue in C:\xampp\htdocs\bagnew11\group\values.php on line 19
jan//

Comment: this is what i added in sql query before it displays the above error   $result = mysql_query("SELECT month, sum(revenue) FROM sample GROUP BY month") or die ("Error");

Comment: this code is what i have at line 19   echo $row['month'] . "/" . $row['revenue']. "/";

Comment: If all you changed was the SQL query, then you'll have to modify your $row reference. Either use an "AS" keyword in the query or change to the index - $row[0] / $row[1]